# Cannot parse message published in Pub/Sub job update notification for google transcoder

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

Business Impact: Not being able to use the Pub/Sub job update notifications feature. Issue Summary: We (Recall) are trying to use the Pub/Sub notifications for job updates (https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/create-pub-sub).

However, since the PubsubMessage data is serialized into bytes [1], without knowing the proto type, we cannot deserialize it [2]. (Unless the intention is to treat the data as a string and parse from there?)

Based off the message we see published in the Pub/Sub topic:

```
data: "{\"job\":{\"name\":\"projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/us-central1/jobs/JOB_ID\",\"state\":\"SUCCEEDED\",\"failureReason\":null}}"
message_id: "2356400951506061"
publish_time {
  seconds: 1620063162
  nanos: 430000000
}
```

We were guessing that the type is google.cloud.video.transcoder.v1beta1.Job [3], but parsing the message into that type throws InvalidProtocolBufferException.
Is this the type we should be using to deserialize the message? Any tips to help parse the published message would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pubsub message in v1beta1 doesn't refer to any protos. The data is in json form so I think you could "treat the data as a string and parse from there".

The message in transcoder v1 will be in proto format. The doc has not been updated yet. Please check later

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

Here is documentation, they have mentioned we need to convert the buffer to string and then we can parse the data.

```
  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  let messageCount = 0;
    const messageHandler = message => {
      console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
      console.log(`\tData: ${message.data}`);
      console.log(`\tAttributes: ${message.attributes}`);
      messageCount += 1;

      // "Ack" (acknowledge receipt of) the message
      message.ack();
    };

    // Listen for new messages until timeout is hit
    subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
```

I have tried the same

1. converting buffer to a string
2. parsing the string

   ```
   let stringData = message.data.toString();
   console.log(stringData);
   let jsonData = JSON.parse(stringData);
   console.log(jsonData);
   ```

This worked for me in **javascript**